# Error on install gem factory_girl and ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I try to install [skylinecms](http://www.skylinecms.nl/documentation/guides/getting_started) but I have a problem with installing the gem.
The gem [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) asked me to use version> = 1.9.2  of Ruby

```
atmoner@atmoner:~/base_ror$ sudo gem install skylinecms
ERROR:  Error installing skylinecms:
    factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

ruby -v

```
atmoner@atmoner:~/base_ror$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]
```

I have tried to change ruby version to 1.9.2

```
atmoner@atmoner:~/base_ror$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /home/atmoner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
```

But still same problem

```
atmoner@atmoner:~/base_ror$ sudo gem install skylinecms
ERROR:  Error installing skylinecms:
    factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

what's the source of this problem?
you have an idea?

Comment: You installed it as a gem, do you get the same problems when you clone it from the repository?  Also, it may help to know what version of Rails you are running.

Comment: For me it worked fine..I have the same version like you..Are you sure you are not behind a firewall or something? Try downloading the gem from here http://rubygems.org/gems/factory_girl and install it manually from your local drive..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `sudo` with `rvm`, as it creates a new subshell with a completely new environment. See more about sudo and rvm here: [RVM and 'sudo'](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/qt/Rvm-And-Sudo.htm)

Most likely your `system ruby` version is `1.8.7`, and that is what is getting invoked when you run `sudo gem install skylinecms`. You can verify that with the following commands:

```
rvm use system
ruby -v
```

Try installing the `skylinecms` gem without `sudo`.

Best to use per-project gemsets as suggested in [rvm best practices](https://rvm.io/rvm/best-practices/)